# Realm - Add file with initial data to project (iOS/Swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, realm

I'm developing an application for iOS using swift and chose Realm as a database solution for it. I wrote default data in AppDelegate using write/add function from realm docs and it works just fine. So after first launch I have a *.realm file with my initial data. In Realm documentation I found a section called ["Bundling a Realm with an App"](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#bundling-a-realm-with-an-app), I add my *.realm file to project and to Build Phases as it written.

And I can't understand what I should do next (and part about compressing a *.realm file). I've tried to understand a code from [Migration Example](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/examples/ios/objc/Migration/AppDelegate.m) but I don't know Obj-C well.

Please give as clear steps as you can to add *.realm file with initial data to swift ios project and load this data to the Realm db with the first launch.

Comment: What exactly is unclear? The link to the documentation already describes all the steps that are necessary in order to add a seed database to your app.

Comment: The main question I suppose is how to access data from loaded file in code. When I create Realm() in code that's ok. But how to "open" this file in code in order to load data from it to app database? Or how to use this file as db itself (as i understood from last point of Building a Realm with an App section it is possible).

Comment: Never worked with Realm, but as stated in Point 6 of the documentation , you can just call Realm(path:) with the appropriate path.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Implement this function `openRealm` in AppDelegate and call it in

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool { 
    ...
    openRealm() 

    return true
 }

func openRealm() {

    let defaultRealmPath = Realm.defaultPath
    let bundleReamPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath?.stringByAppendingPathComponent("default.realm")

    if !NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(defaultRealmPath) {
        NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtPath(bundleReamPath!, toPath: defaultRealmPath, error: nil)
    }
}
```

It will copy your realm file that you bundled in the app to the default realm path, if it doesn't exist already. After that you use Realm normally like you used before.

There's also the Migration example that you talked about in [Swift](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/examples/ios/swift/Migration/AppDelegate.swift).

In Swift 3.0.1 you may prefer this:

```
    let defaultRealmPath = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!
    let bundleRealmPath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "seeds", withExtension: "realm")

    if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: defaultRealmPath.absoluteString) {
        do {
            try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: bundleRealmPath!, to: defaultRealmPath)
        } catch let error {
            print("error copying seeds: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

(but please be careful with the optionals)

Comment: And one more quiestion. Before I read your answer I did myself my default.realm file in project folder as working realm db file (didn't want it but it was simple). Data reads ok from it, my function that writes data works with no errors and writes a data (I add println(<query for last added item>) and it gives me created item) but when I open default.realm in Browser (or rerun an app) there is no new data only initial one.

Comment: updated link to migration example: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/examples/ios/swift-2.2/Migration/AppDelegate.swift

Answer (score 4):

Swift version 3, courtesy of [Kishikawa Katsumi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1733883/kishikawa-katsumi):

```
let defaultRealmPath = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!
let bundleReamPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "default", ofType:"realm")

if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: defaultRealmPath.path) {
do
{
    try FileManager.default.copyItem(atPath: bundleReamPath!, toPath: defaultRealmPath.path)
}
catch let error as NSError {
    // Catch fires here, with an NSError being thrown
    print("error occurred, here are the details:\n \(error)")
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

And for those that need @pteofil's answer in Objective-c

```
- (void)openRealm {
    NSString *defaultRealmPath = [RLMRealm defaultRealm].path;
    NSString *bundleRealmPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"default.realm"];
    if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:defaultRealmPath]) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:bundleRealmPath toPath:defaultRealmPath error:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: You mixed up `stringByAppendingPathComponent` and `stringByAppendingString`.

Answer (score 1):

Updating @pteofil's openRealm function for Swift 2.2/Realm 1.0.2:

```
func openRealm() {

    let defaultURL =  Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!        
    let bundleReamPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("default", withExtension: "realm")


    if !NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(defaultURL.path!) {
        do {
        try NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtURL(bundleReamPath!,  toURL: defaultURL)
         }
        catch {}
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Work in the enterprise space, I need to open a Realm for each application without reusing Realm across all applications so I put this together for Swift 3.0.  Add this function to the AppDelegate.

```
func openRealm()
   {
      let appName = "ApplcationNameGoesHere"
      var rlmConfig = Realm.Configuration()
      let defaultRealmPath = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!
      let appRealmPath = defaultRealmPath.deletingLastPathComponent().appendingPathComponent("\(appName).realm")
      if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: appRealmPath.path) {
     // Use the default directory, but replace the filename with the application name: appName
         rlmConfig.fileURL = rlmConfig.fileURL!.deletingLastPathComponent().appendingPathComponent("\(appName).realm")

     }else
      {
         rlmConfig.fileURL = appRealmPath
      }
      // Set this as the configuration used for the default Realm
      Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = rlmConfig      
   }// open the Realm database for the application
```

The code above opens or creates a Realm with the file name of "ApplicationNameGoesHere.realm" based on the appName variable in this example.

place

```
openRealm() before return true in application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
      // Override point for customization after application launch.
      openRealm()

      return true
```

}

call it in another class like this:

```
let uiRealm = try! Realm()
```

Comment: A little suggestion: it is always safer to unwrap the optional fileURL path component and only proceed with the function once you have a non optional path...even if it is fiddly and annoying to do, it's good practice and becomes automatic eventually.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open it straight from the bundle location and not bother copying it to the default Realm path, look at the implementation [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/2896)

Answer (score 0):

Download Realm Studio in your system. Then print the path from Xcode and copy it:

```
print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!)
```

Then open the terminal and write:

```
open //file path
```

It will open the file in Realm Studio and you can see your model data there.