# Realm query Object property field by its property

Tags: ios, swift, database, realm

I'm developing an application for iOS using Swift and chose Realm as a database solution for it. I asked [one question about Realm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30476179/realm-add-file-with-initial-data-to-project-ios-swift) and now I have another.

Suppose we have a schema like this:

```
class Person: Object {
    dynamic var id: String = NSUUID().UUIDString
    dynamic var name: String?
    dynamic var cars: Car?

class Car: Object {
    dynamic var name: String?
```

I have one class (Person) that contains any number of objects of another class (Car). Car that are "linked" with the Person has some properties in context of that Person (and they can be different for same Car for different Persons or for two similar Cars for one Person). Using List<...>() we can not store such properties for each Item, am I right?

If we use Car only for one Person and only once we can create another class that includes only additional properties for Cars and links them with ID of Person plus ID of Car. But it does't work if we have two similar Cars with different additional properties.

So, how I see the solution. Have one table (class) stores ID of Person, ID of one Car and additional properties for this Car. For another Car for the same Person it has the same Person ID, Car ID (same or not) and another additional properties for this instance of a Car.

There is a problem (and a question that I mean). Having that structure I want **to query all Cars from that table with their additional properties that have Person ID equals to some_id**. How should I do this? Or maybe what another structure (maybe using List<...>) I should have to achieve such kind of behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is `FastList` exactly ?

If you want `Items` to have a property of `Lists` collection.

You have to redefine your Realm model. something like this.

```
class Car:Object{
    dynamic var createDate: NSDate = NSDate()
}
class Person:Object{
    let cars = List<Car>()
}
```

and query by predicate like this

```
let realm = Realm()
var ownedCarsFilterByDate = realm.objects(Person).filter("ANY cars.createDate = '\(date)'")
```

---

*Edited to updated question*

Your solution is to create table class, which has 'Person' , 'Car' and 'Context Attribute'.

Your model would be like this

```
class PersonAndCarRelation:Object{

    dynamic var person: Person?
    dynamic var car: Car?
    dynamic var contextAttribute = ""

}
```

and you can query all cars associated with person

```
    let personID = "123456789"
    let personAndCarArray = realm.objects(PersonAndCarRelation).filter("person.id == \(personID)")
    for personAndCar in personAndCarArray{
        let personName = personAndCar.person.name
        let carName = personAndCar.car.name
        let context = personAndCar.contextAttribute
        println("I am \(personName). I have a \(carName) with \(context)")
    }
```

Comment: You might also want to query for any cars.createDate >= '\(date)' depending on if you are looking for any cars created after or before a specific date

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for. Quite simple, some of predicates were unclear for me I'll work on it. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, not EXACTLY... I have on class (List) that contains any number of objects of another class (Item). Your solution is clear but I missed one thing. Item that are in the List has some properties in context of that list (and they are different for one Item in different Lists or for two the same Items in one list). Using List<...>() we can note store such properties for each Item, am I right?

Comment: The question is unclear for me. Because you use 'Lists' and 'List' word in your example. Since 'List' is a RealmObject class ( https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest ), and 'Lists' is your defined class. So I recommend you to change your defined class name to be like 'Car' and 'Person', to make the question clearer.