# How to access properties of an object returned from primary key query in Realm Swift

Tags: swift, realm

Here is my code:

```
 func jobSelected() {

    let businessName = realm.objects(UserSettings.self).last

    let results = realm.object(ofType: Job.self, forPrimaryKey: "uuid")

    print(results)

    businessNameLabel.text = "Bid From  \(businessName!.businessName)"
    jobNameLabel.text = "Job Name  \(results?.name)"
    jobAddressLabel.text = results?.address
    jobPhoneLabel.text = results?.phone
}
```

The function returns the correct uuid, but the other properties (results?.name, results?.address, results?.phone) return nil.  These properties are used to populate labels in a tableview cell.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

A slight correction:  I am actually clicking on a tableview cell and segueing into another view.  Then I call the jobSelected function and I'm trying to put the values of the results obtained into regular labels in a UIView.  I can't imagine that matters because all I am passing in the segue is the actual uuid string that comes from a cell label.

Here are the contents of my model class:
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

```
class Job: Object {

dynamic var name = ""
dynamic var address = ""
dynamic var phone = ""
dynamic var email = ""
dynamic var date = ""
dynamic var jobName = ""
dynamic var tripChg = 0.0
dynamic var notes = ""
dynamic var discount = 0.0
dynamic var uuid = NSUUID().uuidString
var rooms = List<Room>()

override static func primaryKey() -> String {
    return "uuid"


}

let room = LinkingObjects(fromType: Room.self, property: "job")
var thisJob: Room? {return room.first}

convenience init(uuid: NSUUID) {
    self.init()
    self.uuid = ""
}
```

}

Comment: Is your primary key literally the string `uuid`? If your results are nil that's probably because no object with that UUID exists in the database.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the object actually has values set for those other properties? What gets printed in the `print(results)` line? What does the Realm Browser show you for the object with that primary key?

Comment: Yes they all have values.  I'm using the Realm Browser which shows all values as they are entered, and printing the properties in the console when I save them.  I use default values on the screen where they are entered so that none of the properties in the model are nil.  The print results line is "A4C5971F-AD49-437A-95BD-06FA94C8E9E3", which is the uuid as seen in Realm Browser.

Comment: Please share the declaration of your model class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

the line in the function that was wrong was:

```
let results = realm.object(ofType: Job.self, forPrimaryKey: "uuid)
```

It should be:

```
let results = realm.object(ofType: Job.self, forPrimaryKey: (segueLabel.text!))
```

The segueLabel holds the actual value of the "uuid" property.  I'm learning... slowly.

Thanks to all who responded!

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31006930/4525734

This provide clean picture of how to use Realm and also get object properties.

Also, I referred to this tutorial to understand more about realm and using it with swift. I hope it will be useful.

https://www.appcoda.com/realm-database-swift/

Comment: As far as I can see my code is correct.  I am getting the results via the primary key method versus the filter using predicate.  I have used both and get the same results, meaning, the property value of the "uuid" is returned, but the other property values of the object are returned nil.