# Realm data doesn't show up on a physical device

Tags: swift, realm

I'm developing an app with realmSwift. I want to set preset data on realm db initially, then I want it to show up when user open the app and to make it writable. I write some code based on other questions about realm bundle. such as [Realm - Add file with initial data to project (iOS/Swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30476179/realm-add-file-with-initial-data-to-project-ios-swift) and [Realm fileExists is always true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43545490/realm-fileexists-is-always-true)
Then I managed to do what I want to on simulator but it doesn't work on a physical device. This is the code I wrote on AppDelegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


    openRealm()

    let config = Realm.Configuration(

        fileURL: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "default", withExtension: "realm"),

        readOnly: true)

    var realm = try! Realm(configuration: config)


    print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL)

    return true
}

func openRealm() {

    let realm = try! Realm()
    let bundlePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "default", ofType: "realm")
    let destPath = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL?.path
    let fileManager = FileManager.default

    if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: destPath!) {
        //File exist, do nothing
        print("File exist")

        try! fileManager.removeItem(atPath: destPath!)

        do {
            //Copy file from bundle to Realm default path
            try fileManager.copyItem(atPath: bundlePath!, toPath: destPath!)
            print("Copied")
        } catch {
            print("\n",error)
        }


    } else {
        do {
            try fileManager.copyItem(atPath: bundlePath!, toPath: destPath!)
            print("Copied")
        } catch {
            print("\n",error)
        }
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 issue with your code: firstly, you shouldn't be using the `true` part of your if branch, since as long as you run `openRealm()` from your AppDelegate's `applicationDidFinishLaunching` and before you'd make any calls to `Realm` the only reason why a `default.realm` file can exist is because your app isn't launching for the first time, so you shouldn't overwrite it.

Secondly, you shouldn't be calling `let realm = try! Realm()` at the beginning of your `openRealm` function since that will actually create a `realm`, which will make harder it than it should be to detect if the prepopulated `.realm` file was already copied to the `defaultPath` or not. You don't actually need to call `try! Realm()` at all in the `openRealm()` function unless you want to perform a migration before your Realm could be opened from anywhere else in your code.

```
func openRealm() {
    let bundlePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "default", ofType: "realm")!
    let defaultPath = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL?.path!
    let fileManager = FileManager.default

    // Only need to copy the prepopulated `.realm` file if it doesn't exist yet
    if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: defaultPath){
    print("use pre-populated database")
    do {
        try fileManager.copyItem(atPath: bundlePath, toPath: defaultPath)
        print("Copied")
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Lastly, you shouldn't be creating a new configuration where you overwrite the path of `Realm` with your `bundlePath` since files in the application bundle shouldn't be modified ever (that will break your code signature). Moreover, you already copied your prepopulated file from your application bundle to Realm's `defaultPath`, so if you simply call `Realm()`, it will be modifying the prepopulated file, since it is stored at the default location.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    openRealm()
    print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL)
    return true
}
```

Comment: The reason why I used true part is because when I just copied the original code on the (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30476179/realm-add-file-with-initial-data-to-project-ios-swift) , realm says fileExist is true always, and It doesn't copy realm db which i put preset data. That's why I use 'try! fileManager.removeItem(atPath: destPath!) ' this method to reset realm db first.

Comment: @Kabalry as I've stated, that shouldn't happen as long as you use the code in my answer. You probably have been initializing a Realm instance before called the copy code. Did you also make sure that you deleted the app before testing it?

Comment: Yes of course, I did. At first time, I tried on my a physical iPhone, it also happened. I cannot figured out why so far. Would you mind checking my code on GitHub?