# Cannot write to my prebundled realm file

Tags: ios, swift, realm

> Cannot convert value of type '() -> ()' to expected argument type 'Data?

this is what I get for this line: `try realm.writeCopy(toFile: url) {`

I have no idea how to write to the opened prebundled database

```
        for question in questionBank! {
            do{
                let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "questions", ofType: "realm")!)
                try realm.writeCopy(toFile: url) {
                    question.answered = false
                    print(question.answered)
                }
            } catch {
                print("ERROR ZEROING QUESTIONS")
            }
        }
```

Comment: how you insatiate `realm` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`writeCopy(toFile:)` is not an alternative to using `write`. It actually copies your existing `.realm` file and copies it to the URL supplied as the input argument.

You need to call a regular `write` transaction if you want to modify your `.realm` file and create a copy of the `.realm` **before** modifying it if you want to store several versions.

However, you'll run into troubles soon if you are modifying bundled files since that will break the code signature of your application. If you want to use a prepopulated `.realm` file from the application `Bundle`, first copy it to the default location used by realm, then you can simply write to the default realm. If you don't know how to copy a prepopulated Realm file to the default location, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50485420/4667835) answer of mine.

Comment: That is the problem I have a quiz app and I made a realm file with the questions which I want to ship and be able to modify

Comment: @ADProgress so just copy the bundled file as I've explained and you'll be good.

Comment: Thank you very much this solved a huge part of my issue:) Koszi szepen!