# What happens to Realm database when the user updates the IOS app from the Appstore?

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

Currently I have an iOS app with Realm DB.When I update my iOS app, all data are deleted. How can I keep all data after updating my app.

Thx

Comment: An update leaves data in place. Only the applicatio. Package bundle is replaced

Comment: Are you shipping a preloaded Realm db file with your app? From the minimal amount of information provided in your question it seems to me that you are using a repopulated Realm file incorrectly (check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50483432/realm-data-doesnt-show-up-on-a-physical-device/50485420#50485420) for how to do that correctly) and not copying it outside of the bundle, but instead modifying it as part of the bundle, hence it will be replaced during an app update.